# VBA editor behavior: new window when new file is opening

Tags: excel, vba, editor

How to make the VBA editor do not change the foreground window when a new Excel file is opening (it is changing to one of the modules of the opened file)?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHxVG.png)

Comment: Close all windows of the file you plan to open and save it.

Comment: Kind of solution, thank you. Is the way to close them all at once?